# How should I deal with 产生 in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I have this sentence below, but I don't really know how to deal with 产生。Any suggestions? I have basically ignored it. 1. was my first attempt, then I wrote 2., which I prefer. Does that agree with the sense of the Chinese sentence?

求职者一定要先确认自己签订的劳动合同是否具备产生法律约束力的条件。

1. The job seeker should definitely first check for himself, whether or not the employment contract he is about to sign has legally binding conditions.
2. The job seeker should definitely first check for himself, whether or not the employment contract he is about to sign is legally binding.

Comment: The job applicant should be sure to first verify that the terms of the labor contract are legally binding. 

just treat 产生法律约束力 as a phrase meaning 'to be legally binding'

Comment: The sentence is unnecessarily wordy and can certainly be trimmed to 求职者一定要确认签订的合同是否具备法律约束 without losing the original meaning.

Answer (score 1):

求职者一定要先确认自己签订的劳动合同是否**具备产生法律约束力的条件**。Let us first simplify the latter half of the sentence.

求职者一定要先确认自己签订的劳动合同是否**具备条件**。What kind of 条件 does it 具备？**产生法律约束力的条件** - the condition that leads to legally binding

If you literally translate "产生", it means *produce*. Which would make sense to extend its meaning to *lead to*. So if I am translating your sentence, I will do it this way:

Job seekers should definitely first check for themselves, whether or not the employment contract he is about to sign leads to the condition of legally binding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't get the sentence components completely right in your translations. The rough separation of components should be:

求职者/一定要先确认/自己签订的劳动合同/是否具备/产生法律约束力的/条件。

Job seekers/must confirm first/the labor contracts signed by (them)selves/whether have/legally binding power-generating/conditions.

To put it in normal order of English:

Job seekers must confirm first whether the labor contracts signed by themselves have conditions which generate legally binding power.

The "自己" means not "check for himself" but a part of "自己签订的劳动合同", e.g. labor contracts signed by himself.

"产生" here serves as a connection between "conditions"(条件) and "legally binding power"(法律约束力). It modifies "conditions" to mean those are conditions that generate "legally binding power"

Answer (score 0):

产生 makes this sentence more strict. I think it has the same meaning with 求职者一定要先确认自己签订的劳动合同是否具备法律约束力, ignore 产生 and 条件 simultaneously may be easier to understand.